# Как перенести базу данных sql server при помощи скрипта

Tags: sql, sql-server

Была сделана и наполнена данными база и теперь требуется перенести ее на sql server университета. Из-за ограничений я не могу просто прикрепить ее к серверу, преподаватель посоветовал сгенерировать скрипт в MSSMS. Подскажите способ, как можно это сделать.

Comment: Как это прикрепить не можете? Не понятно..,
Снять дамп и перекинуть в университетскую сеть есть возможность?

Comment: Мы сильно ограничены в правах при использовании университетского сервера. Как я понимаю, я не могу через дамп это сделать. @KonstantinFedorov

Comment: `ПКМ на БД >> Tasks >> Generate Scripts...`, а дальше уже там галочки расставляйте как нужно

Comment: https://info-comp.ru/create-script-in-ms-sql-server
В ответ не кину, не по дзену это, но описывать сам не хочу)